# psql: command not found Mac

Tags: macos, bash, postgresql, psql

I installed PostgreSQL via the graphical install on http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/

I see it in my applications and also have the psql terminal in my applications. I need psql to work in the regular terminal for another bash script I'm running for an app.

For some reason, when I run

```
psql
```

in the Mac terminal, my output is

```
-bash: psql: command not found
```

I ran the following in the terminal:

```
locate psql | grep /bin
```

and the output was

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/psql
```

I then edited my ~/.bash_profile and added it to the path like so:

```
export PATH = /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/psql:$PATH
```

The only other thing in ~/.bash_profile is SDK man and it's at the bottom of the script as it says it should be. I've tried setting the bath to just the /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/ as well. I've restarted my terminal also.

How can I get psql to work?

**EDIT**
After adding to .bashrc, this output is returned when I open terminal

```
-bash: export: `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: You have got the PATH slightly wrong. You need the PATH to *"the containing directory"*, not the actual executable. Your PATH should be `export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin:$PATH` - without the extra `psql` bit in it. And also, you must remove the spaces around the equals sign.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've tried that as well and it still returns psql: command not found

Comment: Can you give the output of `echo $PATH` please?

Comment: /Users/name/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: I just added an edit - there is an issue w/ the path.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I didn't see removing the spaces. That worked - if you want to add the answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You have got the PATH slightly wrong. You need the PATH to *"the containing directory"*, not the actual executable itself.

Your PATH should be set like this:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin:$PATH
```

without the extra `sql` part in it. Also, you must remove the spaces around the equals sign.

Comment: just RESTART YOUR TERMINAL, that might be all it is

Comment: Never, never, never forget the `:$PATH` at the end of this command, or it's gonna hit the fan and paralyze the shell :p

Comment: Actually didn't realise I needed to install something, now it works, thanks :)

Comment: for Mojave users: export PATH=/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.5/bin:$PATH

Comment: If you simply want to pin a single version of postgresql and still have the binaries in the default PATH, you can also run `brew link postgresql@9.5 --force`.

Comment: if you work with "zsh", make sure you are modifying files with "z" prefix. It cost me an hour =(

Comment: try echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@9.5/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Comment: Running `brew link postgresql@16 --force` solved the issue for me. I didn't even need to update my `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 52):

From the Postgres [documentation page:](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html)

```bash
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d && \
  echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin \
  | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```

restart your terminal and you will have it in your path.

Comment: The instructions also say "Of course, you could also just edit your .profile file instead."
My cli install did not work until I did this on MacOS 10.12 Sierra with Postgres 10 (the sudo command did not work for me):


`vi ~/.profile
add this line: export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/bin
.source ~/.profile`

Comment: `postgresapp.com` is not an official Postgres documentation.

Comment: This did not work on an m2

Answer (score 48):

**N.B. The following answer has been edited to correct a dangerous typo in the edit of PATH! (see comments below)**

For me this worked:

1. Downloading the App: https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html
2. Running commands to configure $PATH - note though that it didn't work for me.  https://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html
3. Manually add it to the .bash_profile or .zshrc document if you are using zsh:

   ```
    cd  # to get to your home folder
    open .bash_profile  # to open your bash_profile
    # Or
    open .zshrc  # to open your zshrc
   ```

   In your bash .profile or .zshrc add:

   ```
    # Postgres
    export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH
   ```

   Save the file. Restart the terminal. Type 'psql'. Done.

Comment: I thought this one was the solution for me but When I modified the .zshrc file and add `export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin` suddenly all my zshell features were not working. Whenever I type 'ls', 'open' or another says 'command not found in zsh' .

Comment: @Erick the same happened to me. Beware this answer, folks

Comment: You need to append existing $PATH variable to the newly created one so it does not overwrite everything.
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH

Comment: I had to open .zshrc using this command: `open ~/.zshrc`.  then copy there this line: `export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Original answer edited to correct dangerous suggestion

Answer (score 32):

If someone used homebrew with Mojave or later:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.5/bin:$PATH
```

change version if you need!

Answer (score 23):

Mojave, Postgres was installed via

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lembacon/homebrew-core/bede8a46dea462769466f606f86f82511949066f/Formula/postgresql@9.6.rb
```

How to get psql in your path:

```
brew link postgresql@9.6 --force
```

Comment: Forcing brew to use the given postgresql version works for me.

Answer (score 13):

If Postgresql was downloaded from official website. After installation, running these commands helped me resolve the **psql** issue.

Go to your home directory with `cd ~`

In your home directory, run `ls -a`. Edit the *.bash_profile* file with **vim**

`vi .bash_profile` opens the vim editor.

Insert  by pressing `i` on the editor.

Add `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/<Version Number>/bin`

The `Version Number` refers to the version number of the postgresql installed on your local machine. In my case, **version 12** was installed, so I inputed

`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin` .

Press the `esc` key and press `:wq` to exit the editor.

Enter `source .bash_profile` in your terminal to read and execute the content of a file just passed as an argument in the current shell script.

Run `psql`

[terminal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pjAd.png)

In summary:

- `cd ~`
- `vi .bash_profile`
- `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin` *Take note of the version number*
- `exit vim`
- `source .bash_profile`
- `psql` Works

Comment: +1, don't understand why all the hustle, why not set things up automatically during the UI installation process

Comment: `vi .zshrc` for modern macos using zsh and at the end `source .zshrc`

Comment: For the exit vim
1) Save and exit: If you want to save your changes and exit vim, you can use the :wq command.
2) Exit without saving: If you don't want to save your changes and just want to exit vim, you can use the :q!

Answer (score 11):

For **MacOs Monterey 12.4:**

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/<postgres version>/bin
```

Example : (That works for me) PostgreSQL version 14

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/14/bin
```

Then run : `exec zsh -l` to restart the teminal

Good luck!!

Answer (score 7):

If Postgres was downloaded and installed, running this should fix the issue:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee 
/etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```

Restart the terminal and you'll be able to use `psql` command.

Ref: https://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html

Answer (score 5):

Modify your `PATH` in `.bashrc`, not in `.bash_profile`:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: I have also added to the .bashrc - still returns the same output.

Comment: Marked up for useful information, though it did not solve my specific problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes I didn't spot the extra spaces in your `PATH` line before Mark pointed that out. :-) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

I installed `postgresql@13` with `Homebrew` on `Mac`, and I followed the given instructions in the `zsh` terminal after installation.

> postgresql@13 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into
> /usr/local,because this is an alternate version of another formula.
>
> If you need to have postgresql@13 first in your PATH, run:
> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@13/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

> For compilers to find postgresql@13 you may need to set:
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/postgresql@13/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/postgresql@13/include"

> For pkg-config to find postgresql@13 you may need to set:
> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@13/lib/pkgconfig"

> To restart postgresql@13 after an upgrade:
> brew services restart postgresql@13

> Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can
> just run:
> /usr/local/opt/postgresql@13/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@13

You can check if the path is added by running:
`open .zshrc`
and restart the `zsh` terminal after: `exec zsh -l`

Answer (score 4):

**ANSWERED ON OCTOBER 2017**

run

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin:$PATH
```

and then restart your terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Open the file `.bash_profile` in your Home folder. It is a hidden file.

Add this path below to the end export PATH line in you `.bash_profile` file
`:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

The symbol `:` separates the paths.

#### Example:

If the file contains:
`export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

it will become:
`export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

#### How to show hidden files

In Terminal, paste the following: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`

Answer (score 3):

As a postgreSQL newbie I found the os x setup instructions on the postgresql site impenetrable. I got all kinds of errors. Fortunately the uninstaller worked fine.

```
cd /Library/PostgreSQL/11; open uninstall-postgresql.app/
```

Then I started over with a brew install followed by this article [How to setup PostgreSQL on MacOS](https://www.robinwieruch.de/postgres-sql-macos-setup)

It works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Your path is not defined correctly.
Run this command in your terminal:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/<your psql version>/bin/"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

`zshrc` is for you if you are using MacOS Catalina or a newer version.

Answer (score 2):

After installing with homebrew, it yields the following instruction:

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Which works after restarting the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I know some others have already mentioned that the path needs to be updated however for me it did not work **till I added the path itself in quotations**. I an not 100% sure why that happened for me but this is the command that worked for me (on MacOS Terminal)

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.5/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have updated my `.bash_profile` and added Postgres path as shown on some of the answers here but running `psql` in Terminal still gave me a command not found error.

Had to update `.zprofile` file and add the Postgres path and it worked!

Steps in Terminal:

1. `nano ~/.zprofile`
2. Add this on the end of PATH: `/Library/PostgreSQL/14/bin:${PATH}` Note: Mind the version number
3. Save your changes. `Ctrl + o` then `Ctrl + x`
4. `source .zprofile`

Comment: Thank! this is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got **Postgres.app** installed on macOS:

You can check path with command below (*Optional step*):

```
ls /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

If so, just add this line in the end of `~/.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:"$PATH"
```

Then just close and open terminal and `psql` command should works well.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for macbook

1. Open .zshrc file:

nano .zshrc

2. Add into file(Do not add to the end of file cause some libs like sdk etc must be at the end):

export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH

3. Save file.
4. Restart terminals.
5. Check psql access:

psql

> psql (16.1)
> Type "help" for help.